# What is the difference between these two types of return?

Tags: c++, return-value

I have empty class(just for example):

```
class A { ; };
```

I tried two types of creating new A class object in function and return this:
1)

```
A getA1()
{
    A a;
    return a;
}
```

2)

```
A getA2()
{
    A* a = new A;
    return *a;
}
```

What is the difference between them if I get the same result?

Comment: *What is the difference between them if I get the same result?* -- Write a `main` program that uses both methods correctly, i.e. no memory leaks.  You can't do it with the second method.  What good is the "result" if your code leaks memory?

Comment: @Alex hint: add a destructor to out ~A() { std::cout << "A Destroyed"; }

Comment: Clang under `-O3` compiles both to `ret`. :)

Comment: The second is less performant and will leak memory. The first will will not.

Comment: As I understand at the function ```getA1()``` I can't free the memory, because it allocated before the program starts. At the function ```getA2()``` memory allocation is dynamic and it will not  be allocated before the program have been executed?

Comment: @Evg clever girl. I wonder what msvc does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question could actually delve quite deep into the scary inner-workings of memory management in C++. I'm not sure how familiar you are with all of that, so I'll try to answer in a simple manner.

At a surface level, both of these functions do the same thing. You construct a new object, and then return that object. However, the key difference between the two is *where* those objects are stored.

In the first example, what you're doing is returning a copy of the object A that you created earlier in the function. (If you know what a copy constructor is, that's what is called when you run `return a;`.) There are caveats to this (look up "copy elision" if you're interested), but you should think of this as just returning a plain old object that's no different than any other variable you've declared.

In the second example, however, you're **dynamically allocating** a new object called a. Objects that are allocated like this are stored in the **heap**, rather than on the **stack**, and any objects that are allocated eventually need to be de-allocated. If they are not, then this results in a memory leak. It's not safe at all to assume the user of this program will know or remember to `delete` this variable before the program exits, so it's almost never a good idea to return a dynamically allocated pointer like that.

tl;dr the second one has the ability to destroy your computer's RAM.

If you want to know more about the differences and are not familiar with memory in C++, you should definitely research "C++ pointers".